# Что такое heroku?

Tags: развертывание, heroku, облачное-хранилище

Да я прочитал что это облачный сервис где можно развернуть приложения. Это хостинг по сути? Ось там уже есть? Что там уже настроено, а что нужно настроить?

На бесплатном тарифе часы работы приложения дают + написано 1 web/1 worker что здесь имеется ввиду? Один поток? Если там БД развернуть, к ней одновременно 1 запрос или 1 коннект может быть?